# Atribuir função a variável?

Tags: php

Qual a forma correta de realizar a seguinte atribuição:

preg-replace.php

```
<?php
function file_name(){
    $pg = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    echo  $path_parts = pathinfo($pg, PATHINFO_FILENAME);//preg-replace
}
$string = file_name();//<<<---- como fazer isso corretamente
$string_f = preg_replace('/-/',' ',$string);
echo $string_f;//preg replace <<---resultado esperado
?>
```

Por que o resultado é `preg-replace` e não `preg replace`.

Por que não dá erro, simplesmente não resulta como esperado.

Minha dúvida é em como atribuir o resultado da função `file_name()`(a string "preg-replace") a uma variável e depois usar essa variável...

Comment: Verifique esse `echo` onde devia ser `return`. Não entendi bem o propósito da questão. É só um replace no nome do arquivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei bem se é isto que está a procurar mas preciso um pouco de mais detlhes para conseguir uma resposta mais detalhada

```
 function file_name(){
    $pg = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    return pathinfo($pg, PATHINFO_FILENAME);//tem de colocar return
}
$string = file_name();//<<<---- como fazer isso corretamente
$string_f = preg_replace('/-/',' ',$string);
echo $string_f;//preg replace <<---resultado esperado
```

Comment: Vlw man era isso mesmo...

Answer (score 2):

Fiz uma limpeza, removendo coisas desnecessárias.

O que precisa é apenas usar o `return` ao invés do `echo`, dentro da função.

Consulte o manual: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

```
<?php
function file_name() {
    return pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}
$str = str_replace('-', ' ', file_name());
echo $str;
```

O [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace) também não tinha necessidade. Troquei por [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace).

Comment: Vlw man era isso mesmo...

Comment: Viu, fiquei com uma dúvida, qual a vantagem de usar `str_replace`, que poderia tornar o `preg_replace` desnecessário?

Comment: O preg_replace envolve uma execução mais complexa. Só isso. Para substituir um valor exato, é melhor algo mais simples como o str_replace.